# In org mode, how to export slide with bibliography?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I have been trying to include citations in the org file which I then export to beamer and using biblatex.

It seems that slide of bibliography needs specifying environment like `fragile` or `allowpagebreaks`. So far that seems to be the reason why bibliography is not getting printed.

In the header

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{biblaltex}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \bibliography{file.bib}
```

Citation gets written as [[bib::author03]].

```
* References 

#+BEGIN_LaTeX

  \printbibliography

#+END_LaTeX
```

Could you help get the citations working properly in the org-mode ?

Thanks.

Comment: A simple way to add the property BEAMER_OPTS as given in the answer is to do `org-set-property` and select beamer_opts. It will prompt for the input and saves previous choices.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Additional frame options can be specified using the `BEAMER_OPT` property. (You can set it using `org-set-property`, which is bound to `C-c C-x p` by default.)

To get Org to produce a `beamer` presentation PDF with references I also had to customize the value of `org-latex-pdf-process`, making sure that Org runs `bibtex` when exporting to LaTeX. (Note the manually specified `biblatex` backend, too.)

Here's a minimal example.

The main `beamer-test.org` file:

```
#+startup: beamer
#+LaTeX_CLASS: beamer
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \bibliography{file.bib}

* Frame with content
  See \cite{AbramowitzStegun}.

* Frame with references
  :PROPERTIES:
  :BEAMER_OPT: fragile,allowframebreaks,label=
  :END:      
  \printbibliography
```

In my tests the `file.bib` bibliography database contained:

```
@book {AbramowitzStegun,
    EDITOR = {M. Abramowitz and I. A. Stegun},
     TITLE = {Handbook of {M}athematical {F}unctions, with {F}ormulas, {G}raphs,
              and {M}athematical {T}ables},
    SERIES = {Graduate Studies in Mathematics},
 PUBLISHER = {Dover},
   ADDRESS = {New York},
      YEAR = {1965},
}
```

I discovered `BEAMER_OPT` by reading the code of `org-beamer--format-frame` defined in [`ox-beamer.el`](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/tree/lisp/ox-beamer.el?id=release_8.2.10#n391).

Tested using `GNU Emacs 24.4.1` with `Org-mode version 8.2.10`.

Comment: Dont we need to put the \cite{} and \printbibliography in the #+BEGIN_LATEX #+END_LATEX environment ?

Comment: +1 Thanks for the solution. The only thing is that the file.bib must be kept in the same folder as .org file. Although I added \addbibresource{path\to\file.bib}, this doesnt work. Any way to add path to bib file ?

Comment: Another slight issue is that the bibliography year is showing in red color. I tried with a few themes. Is there a way to specify the color to be black only like the rest of the text ? Thanks.

Comment: @Anusha: `#+BEGIN_LATEX` and `#+END_LATEX` is for *special code that should only be present in LaTeX export*; see [Quoting LaTeX](http://orgmode.org/manual/Quoting-LaTeX-code.html) in the Org Mode Manual. If this document will not be exported to other formats, `#+BEGIN_LATEX` and `#+END_LATEX` are not needed.

Comment: @Anusha: The `.bib` file *can* be in a separate directory. (`#+LATEX_HEADER: \bibliography{bib/file.bib}` works for me, for example.) Note, though, that depending on the OS you need to use `/` (Linux, Mac OS X) or `\\` (Windows) as the file separator.

Comment: @Anusha: Regarding year color: this is *really* not about Org or Emacs, but here goes: use `\setbeamercolor*{...}` commands described in [this `tex.stackexchange` answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97627).

Comment: I thought \printbibliography is a latex command and should be embedded in latex envt for export as we are exporting from .org file to beamer. I guess beamer doesnt use addbibresource which I specified in the preamble. Thanks for the link to setbeamercolor command.

Comment: Its surprising that the latex and beamer bibliography conventions are different. My guess was that the colors were different because of default org mode template when exporting to beamer.